# How to /clear armor in inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a puzzle map and am lowering player health using attributes. I want to know how to clear iron pants that the player is NOT wearing (not in the leg slot). I have tried clearing iron pants, but that also removes the pants in the armor slot. The players will have other items in their inventory.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Frank Is there a meta most or something that lists these stock comments?

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. Nope.  It's just mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other thing you can do is clear both pants and then give the player a new set of pants in the appropriate armor slot.

Comment: I am disappointed in myself for not thinking of using a chain command block. Thanks for the quick reply!